# Drools rule for Object type member

Tags: java, drools, kie

I am new to drools, please bear with me if this is a silly question. I have a class member type of `Object` which I am using to store JSON value (passed from frontend), due to unstructured data I am using Object type for a variable. Here's the POJO class.

```
public class Submission {
    @Id
    private String id;
    private String form;
    private String formId;
    private Object data;
    private Date createdAt = new Date();
    private Date modifiedAt = new Date();
    private String state;
    private Boolean isDeleted = false;
    private Boolean valid = false;

    public Boolean getValid() {
        return valid;
    }

    public void setValid(Boolean valid) {
        this.valid = valid;
    }

    public String getForm() {
        return form;
    }

    public void setForm(String form) {
        this.form = form;
    }

    public String getFormId() {
        return formId;
    }

    public void setFormId(String formId) {
        this.formId = formId;
    }

    public Object getData() {
        return data;
    }

    public void setData(Object data) {
        this.data = data;
    }

    public String getState() {
        return state;
    }

    public void setState(String state) {
        this.state = state;
    }

    public Date getCreatedAt() {
        return createdAt;
    }

    public void setCreatedAt(Date createdAt) {
        this.createdAt = createdAt;
    }

    public Date getModifiedAt() {
        return modifiedAt;
    }

    public void setModifiedAt(Date modifiedAt) {
        this.modifiedAt = modifiedAt;
    }

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Boolean getDeleted() {
        return isDeleted;
    }

    public void setDeleted(Boolean deleted) {
        isDeleted = deleted;
    }
}
```

and this is my .drl

```
package rules; 
import com.ics.lcnc.Submission.Submission;
rule "check name is correct"
when
  Submission(data.name == "john")
then
  submission.setValid(true)
end
```

But for above file I get following error when I try to load this file into `KieBuilder`

```
Message [id=3, kieBase=defaultKieBase, level=ERROR, path=rules/123.drl, line=5, column=0
   text=Unable to Analyse Expression data.name == "hashim":
[Error: unable to resolve method using strict-mode: java.lang.Object.name()]
[Near : {... data.name == "hashim" ....}]
```

Seems like rule engine is unable to find nested property of `Object data`. How do I target nested property which will be known to a program at runtime only?

Answer (score 1):

you may try with having the `data` field be converted (eg by Jackson) as a Map following a prototype based approach and then

```java
...
when
  Submission(data["name"] == "john") ...
```

of instead of Map have a JSONNode (and adapt the constraint in the rule), again for the `data` field in your Submission object model.

Comment: Maps have awful performance in Drools, but when dealing with this sort of use case it's probably the path of lease resistance. +1

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas agreed :)